# Is there an elegant way of preventing numpy from slapping a dtype on empty lists?

Tags: python, list, numpy, type-inference

Consider the following example which may look silly but really is a stripped down version of a real world annoyance:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros(5, int)
b = [*range(5)]
for i in reversed(range(5)):
    a[:i] += b[:i]

# Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
# TypeError: Cannot cast ufunc add output from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

This exception is raised at the last iteration because numpy can no longer infer the correct dtype of the rhs list.

It is, of course, easy to explicitly check for empty operands

```
for i in reversed(range(5)):
    if b[:i]:
        a[:i] += b[:i]
```

but I was wondering whether there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: One probably can by changing Numpy. Just to be clear, what behavior would you like to have? The first code snippet should behave like the second one?

Comment: `for i in reversed(range(1,5)):`??

Comment: Or `a[:i] += np.array(b[:i], dtype=a.dtype)`

Comment: @wwii my fault for making a too simple example, but in the real world code the operand sizes are not so easily controlled/predicted.

Comment: It might be difficult to give a definitive answer to this question, because you might have reasons for rejecting some of the obvious work-arounds.  For example, you could convert the addend to an array with the same type as `a` before doing the in-place addition:  `a[:i] += np.array(b[:i], dtype=a.dtype)`.  But don't do that, since it would be more efficient to just convert `b` to an array at the beginning.

Comment: @Trilarion Yep, In a perfect world `[]` would be promoted to something like `array([], dtype=undetermined)` where dtype undetermined would be compatible with any other dtype.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser looks like I really made the example too primitive. Apologies. The real world problem has a list comprehension on the rhs which I can for the time being not get rid of.

Comment: Then wrapping it as `np.array([...], dtype=a.dtype)` might work?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser yes, that will, of course, work.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share what I went for in the end. At least it is short:

```
for i in reversed(range(5)):
    a[:i] += b[:i] or 0

a
# array([0, 3, 4, 3, 0])
```